# Best practice of what folders must not go to DFS-Replication File server?

Tags: active-directory, file-sharing, dfs, dfs-r

I'm using The existing Windows Server 2016 DFS-Replicated file servers across 10 different locations.

Each site offices in different regions and countries across the globes are replicated.
However, there are some files that seem to be stuck or cannot be replicated due to being used or still opened by users in other locations.

I wonder what's the best case or practice in what types of folders are supposed to be on DFS-R and what cannot or must not be put into DFS-R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFSR is a solution for files that are primarily read-only and infrequently modified. DFSR is not a solution for files that remain open or are frequently modified /by multiple users. If that is what you need, a third party product would be the solution.

Comment: That's great, thank you Greg.